# How to use Vue and Array to make a conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, sorting

I have values `XS` `S` `M` loaded as HTML for all sizes `Black` `White` and I have a JSON show available sizes of each color.

I want to add `v-if` when the `XS` is not available in the array `variant_selection.size`  by using `variant_selection.option1` and the values that loaded as HTML `XS` `S` `M`.

Example:

```json
 variant_selection: {
          option1: "Black",
          option2: "XS",
          size: [
          "Black / XS", /// Only black color has XS size
          "Black / S",
          "Black / M",
          "White / S",
          "White / M",
          ],
        },
```

I was trying that but didn't work for me, please help

```html
<span v-if="'variant_selection.option1 / {{ value }}' !== 'variant_selection.size.includes(variant_selection.option1) / {{ value }}' ">.</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span v-if="variant_selection.size.includes(variant_selection.option1 + ' / ' + value)" ..
```

or

```
<span v-if="variant_selection.size.includes(`${variant_selection.option1} / ${value}`)" ..
```

You should not use Mustaches `{{}}` in the Vue `v-if` conditions

See, [Attribute Bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#attribute-bindings)

> Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes. Instead, use a
> `v-bind` directive

### Solution

```js
const { createApp,ref } = Vue

const App = {
  setup() {
    const color = ref('')
    const colors = ['Black','White']
    const size = ref('')
    const sizes = ['XS','S', 'M']
    const selection =  {
          size: [
          "Black / XS", /// Only black color has XS size
          "Black / S",
          "Black / M",
          "White / S",
          "White / M",
          ]
    }
    return {
      color, colors, size, sizes, selection
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  Color: <select v-model="color">
  <option v-for="c in colors">{{c}}</option>
  </select><br/>
  Size: <select v-model="size">
  <option v-for="s in sizes">{{s}}</option>
  </select><br/>
  Combination: {{ `${color} / ${size}` }}<br/>
  <span v-if="selection.size.includes(`${color} / ${size}` )">Combination is present</span>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry forget to mention I used {{}} for liquid and delimiters: ['${', '}'], for Vue